# Get results from more than one table with a stored MySQL procedure in a controller in MVC entity framework 6

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

I am using `Entity Framework 6` in MVC app with `MySQL`(note `MySQL` not `SQL`) database. I call the MySQL Stored Procedure from a controller in MVC with the following code:

```
    List<ProductList> result = ent.Database.SqlQuery<ProductList>(
                                   "call select_product_data(@_surface, @_price)",
                                    new MySqlParameter("_surface", surfaceVal),
                                    new MySqlParameter("_price", priceVal)
                                ).ToList();
```

Here ProductList is the Model with all the properties that procedure returns. The code for my procedure:

```
     CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `select_product_data`
     (
        IN _surface LONG,
        IN _price LONG
     )
     BEGIN

     select * from product where surface < _surface  and price > _price limit 5;
     SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as cnt_total_product;

     END
```

I am getting a list of 5 products in my related `result` object but I am not getting the value of `cnt_total_product` in the result. How can I get both the list as well as `cnt_total_product` value in controller using Entity Framework 6 in MVC?

I have searched for this on the Internet but nothing helped me with `MySQL` and `EF6` in MVC.

Comment: Stackoverflow.com/questions/20317971

Comment: I can't use this approach because my first query is too complex this is just for understanding purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround would be to return exact same columns type with default values like NULL or something if both result set has no matching columns and union the result.
For example

```
select "set1", col1, col2, col3, 0 from product where surface < _surface  and price > _price limit 5;

UNION ALL

SELECT "set2", NULL, NULL, NULL, FOUND_ROWS() as cnt_total_product;
```

Now split these result sets on code side by filtering set1 and set2

Comment: Can't use UNION ALL as table contains more than 1-2 Lack records so it reduce query performence

Comment: Query performance will be impacted if result set that you are returning also contains 1-2 lacs records which I doubt. But if yes then you should think of different approach instead of returning these many records to application.

Comment: I am returning bunch of 12-12 records to my app using LIMIT through paging